# C++ parallel program is very slow on windows (Threading)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am writing a program to run electrical simulations. Each simulation runs in series (no threading), so that the threading may be done to handle thousands of simulations.

I am testing the program on 3 machines:

- Windows machine (Windows 10, Intel i7 4GHZ, 32 GB RAM) -> (MSVC + Intel MKL)
- Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04, Ryzen 5, 3.4 GHz, 24 GB RAM) -> (GCC + Intel MKL)
- MacOS machine (MacBook Air, M1, 8GB RAM) -> (Clang + Apple Accelerate)

When compiling, the only difference between the platforms is that I need to link against different OS-specific implementations of BLAS and LAPACK

I have declared the following parallel for template function:

```
template<typename Index, typename Callable>
static void ParallelFor(Index start, Index end, Callable func) {
    // Estimate number of threads in the pool
    const static unsigned nb_threads_hint = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    const static unsigned nb_threads = (nb_threads_hint == 0u ? 8u : nb_threads_hint);

    // Size of a slice for the range functions
    Index n = end - start + 1;
    Index slice = (Index) std::round(n / static_cast<double> (nb_threads));
    slice = std::max(slice, Index(1));

    // [Helper] Inner loop
    auto launchRange = [&func] (int k1, int k2) {
        for (Index k = k1; k < k2; k++) {
            func(k);
        }
    };

    // Create pool and launch jobs
    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    pool.reserve(nb_threads);
    Index i1 = start;
    Index i2 = std::min(start + slice, end);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i + 1 < nb_threads && i1 < end; ++i) {
        pool.emplace_back(launchRange, i1, i2);
        i1 = i2;
        i2 = std::min(i2 + slice, end);
    }

    if (i1 < end) {
        pool.emplace_back(launchRange, i1, end);
    }

    // Wait for jobs to finish
    for (std::thread &t : pool) {
        if (t.joinable()) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
// prepare the execution plan
std::vector<std::pair<uword, uword>> bounds = prepareParallelChunks((uword) islands.size());

// run in parallel
ParallelFor(0, (int) bounds.size(), [&] (uword k) {

    // run chunk
    run_simulation(islands, res, *_options, bounds[k].first, bounds[k].second);

});
```

This last function is just to show the usage. In principle if I have 8 logical cores, there will be 8 threads.

When executing the program for 2000 simulations, the results are:

- Windows: Logical cores at about 20%, simulation time: 145s.
- Linux: Logical threads at about 100%, simulation time 35s.
- MacOS: Logical threads at about 100%, simulation time 35s.

**Is there something that I should be taking into account under Windows to make the threading use the full potential?**

PS: I've used C++17 standard `parallelfor` algorithm and the same happens, I've used OpenMP and the same happens. I'm using the referenced `parallelfor`ref because it is C++11 compliant and runs in all 3 systems with no modification.

Comment: What does `getThreadNumber()` do? And what value does it return? Also, you'd better use more standard compilers (MSVC, GCC, Clang) rather than Intel MKL. It has long since become obsolete.

Comment: Hi, `getThreadNumber()` returns the number of logical cores. That is 8 in the machines mentioned. Intel MKL is the fastest implementation of BLAS and LAPACK for x86 architechture. The compilers are indeed MSVC, GCC and Clang.

Comment: That's what I'd expect from `getThreadNumber()`. But does it actually do so? That's the question.

Comment: There I chenged it. If you don't know please skip this question. Clearly the issue is not the number of threads but that each of those do not use the 100% of the power available.

Comment: You should try to run the multi-threading on some simple code (that should get benefit from multi-threading) to check whether the issue is due to some complex functions in the run `run_simulation` that are dependent on an external library. If you manage to write a simple enough code then people can actually test it.

Comment: @ALX23z MKL is not a compiler: this is a library implementing the BLAS interface as well as LAPACK and providing some math functions based on the SVML. It is not obsolete but actively developed and in fact one of the most used libraries in high-performance computing. The Intel compiler is ICC and it is not used here.

Comment: What `run_simulation` does? What version of the MKL do you link? Did you configured the MKL correctly? If the MKL run thread in a parallel code this will likely cause your issue. There are different version of the MKL to avoid that and you can tune the number of thread used. See [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-macos-developer-guide/top/working-with-onemkl-cluster-software/setting-the-number-of-openmp-threads.html). Besides this you can use a *thread pool* not to create a LOT of threads in the simulation loop.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hi, I'm linking MKL in single threaded mode precisely because I want to run each simulation in parallel. I believe I'm linking correctly since in serial mode the library does what it is supposed to do. I "manually" created a thread pool with `std::vector<std::thread> pool` and I make sure to split the task manually before sending them to the parallelfor, so that I only send (in my case) 8 tasks.  This effect on windows is something I did observe before using python code and Qt threading as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the per-core load in more detail? Are you actually getting some utilization across all cores, or 100% utilization on just a few? If the former, have you looked at [wpa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/wpa-quick-start-guide) to get more detail on why the utilization is so low? IIRC there is a "hotspot analyzer" in Visual Studio that does some rudimentary tracing and analysis for you.

Comment: Also, please clarify the exact arguments being passed to `cl.exe`. You should be able to increase the build verbosity to determine this.

Comment: thanks, I've observed a consistent ~20% in all the cores in threading mode, whereas in single thread mode it is a 100% "jumping" from core to core which is expected. I'll have a look at WPA and will try to get the arguments to cl.exe.

Comment: The call to `cl.exe` is like this `cl   
/TP 
-DARMA_USE_SUPERLU=1 
-D_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS 
-IC:armadillo-10.7.4\include 
-IC:pybind11\2.8.1\include 
...
 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -std:c++17 
 /FoCMakeFiles\target.dir\src\myfile.cpp.obj 
 /FdCMakeFiles\target.dir\ /FS -c 
myfile.cpp`

Comment: You can run your simulation in sequential and check the CPU usage of all cores to check if the MKL is correctly linked. In fact, I would be interesting to know the result of this experiment just to gather more information about the issue. Also, if run_simulation` do some/many system calls, then it might justify why the problem appear.

Comment: Are there a lot of calls to memory allocators in `run_simulation` (Including using classes that allocate, like `std::vector`)? gcc has allocators specifically for multithreading but the standard Visual C++ library does not.

Comment: @JérômeRichard indeed the serial simulation runs exactly as expected taking 100% of a core (and jumping core from time to time)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the functionality that runs inside the threads indeed declare matrices and vector but, once declared they do not change in size. It is all numerical simulations. The results are copied back to a results matrix that is pre-allocated, and that all the threads write to in separated positions. I think there may be something there. But what calls my attention is that under UNIX systems there is no issue whatsoever. In general, I do not use std::vector anywhere inside the code that is executed in the threads, just numerical vector and matrices from ArmadilloC++.

Comment: Could this be a thread affinity issue? where windows in shifting all the 8 threads among all the 8 cores, hence the bad performance?

Comment: While schedulers of most mainstream systems are quite bad for embarrassingly parallel programs and indeed tends to cause many context switches, it would be very surprising that the Windows scheduler does not affect any threads to some core. It would be clearly a bug of Windows and I never saw such a behavior yet. I am pretty sure the problem comes from (hidden) locks, syscalls or thread oversubscribtion. Since the two last are unexpected in your code, it is likely due to (hidden) locks. However, this is almost impossible to tell where without having the code of the main computing function...

Comment: You could try to replace the content of your `run_simulation` function by a basic useless for loop (while being careful the compiler does not optimize it). If the problem is still there, then it means it is not related to this function. Otherwise, we need more information.

Comment: Does the problem also appear if you use `std::for_each(std::execution::par,...)` instead of your own pet monstrosity?

Comment: yep, indeed the pet monstosity is there because macos' clang does not support `std::execution` yet...  In fact as I've mentioned it appears in equivalent python code (UNIX: fine, windows: not fine)

Comment: Creating threads is slow under windows, so its not shocking to me that its slower. Have you tried using std::async? I'm not 100% sure, but i believe std::async uses thread pooling. If not, you should look into tapping into whatever thread pooling windows provides.

Comment: @Taekahn thanks, that could indeed be. Let me try and I'll report back.

Comment: If a CPU at 100% does a job in 35 seconds, then a CPU at 20% would do it at 175 seconds, which is roughly what you got on Windows. It has nothing to do with the code that you placed above, which in itself should execute in less than a millisecond. The problem is within the code that's NOT displayed here. That code is likely waiting on the kernel for something, perhaps I/O or contention.

Comment: Hi @Jellyboy, I'm examining the code for any possible lock, but it is hard since most of it is just declaration of armadillo vectors and matrices, and matrix-vector operations, loops etc. No I/O whatsoever, in fcat I removed all uses of std::vector or array that is not declaring its size upfront. What puzzles me the most is that the same code works fine for UNIX,

Comment: Have you tried using profiling tools? If locking in threads is shredding your performance, or if something else is unexpectedly slow in the main thread sequential code, this should help uncover it. The [threads view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/threads-view-parallel-performance?view=vs-2022) in the VS profiler may be able to help do just that.

Comment: Download and run Intel VTune (from Intel OneAPI Toolset). This is a great (free) profiler from Intel that will exactly answer your question. It cannot only tell you the hotspots, where the CPU is working, it will also give you a clear picture of where the threads are waiting and for what.

Comment: Don't really know of any windows limitations that would cause this. Did you confirm that your windows machine's hardware is OK? I'd start by removing code until it goes to 100% utilization. Not going to ask if windows is on emulation.

Comment: I did all the profiling and code stripping and no improvement. The solution came from rewriting all the clases and functions so that no class member is modified once a class is created. I also deleted the clases hosting calculation methods and now I have those as functions and structs. Whith those changes windows runs at full capacity. Apparently there is a much larger penalty in windows if you modify class members inside threads.

Comment: I do not see how modifying a member of a class can impact the parallelism (use of cores) unless there is a serious compiler bug somewhere. And if so, it would be great to report it so it can be fixed. This can still impact performance though (eg. false sharing, constant propagation, etc.). Note that modifying a program can result in the modification of the alignment of some variables that could reveal (performance) bugs or just hide existing one.

Comment: The way I see it, is that the cost of modifying a memory slot becomes quite high when the process is in a thread :/  There mey be an error, or maybe is just a philosophical matter of windows compared to UNIX. However, why on single thread it runs at a 100% but the same operation on multiple threads slows down to 20% is still a mistery that I hope to not to find again.